# Flutter web CORS issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am using flutter-web with .net webapi. To shoot my requests, I have tried Dio and Dart HTTP packages. Neither of the two have worked because of CORS issue. Kindly tell me what am I doing wrong. is there a way to get around this problem ?
There is no problem with api when it comes to shoot them from postman .

Sample code

I have added
`var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("", "", "*"); config.EnableCors();` in webapi as well.

Flutter HTTP Requests first of the two is built on dio.

```
Dio dio= new Dio();
  Future postData2(user) async{
    debugPrint(user.toString());
    dynamic data = {
    'phone_number': user['country_code'] + user['phone_number'],
    'password':user['password']
    };
    final String pathUrl = "http://localhost:62435/api/Token/GetToken";
    var response = await dio.post(pathUrl, data:data, options: Options(
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'true'
        },
    ));
    return response.data;
  }
```

//Http : dart

```
  Future postData(user) async{
    dynamic data = {
      'phone_number': user['country_code'] + user['phone_number'],
      'password':user['password']
    };
    final String pathUrl = "http://localhost:62435/api/Token/GetToken";
    dynamic response = _http.post(
      pathUrl,
      body : data,
      headers : {
        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader : 'application/json',
        //'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'true'
      }
    );
    debugPrint( //response.statusCode +
        " " + response.data.toString());
  }
```

For dio, at least the checkup request is sent
[image]

[image]

[image]

with Dio I get following errors.

Dio Request headers in network tab. The request remains pending. and does not finish.

```
Request URL: http://localhost:62435/api/Token/GetToken
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Referer: http://localhost:63440/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36
{phone_number: "123124", password: "safaSF"}
```

Comment: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:62435/api/Token/GetToken' from origin 'http://localhost:59789'` This line in the error log tells you that you are doing cross domain request. Hence its not getting through you should add the `http://localhost:59789` in the server side as one of allowed origins. However in usual cases for testing in postman this will work because its not from another web domain. For testing purpose in the server side you can allow all domains using a `*` in the server side. If you provide the which server you are using we can find how to configure for the server.

Comment: Hi Abhilash, ive tried  
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors();  
in webapi.

Comment: this is my new request

Future postData(user) async{
    dynamic data = {'phone_number': user['country_code'] + user['phone_number'],'password':user['password']};
    final String pathUrl = "http://localhost:62435/api/Token/GetToken";
      print(jsonEncode(data));
      dynamic response = _http.post(pathUrl,body : jsonEncode(data),headers : {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader : 'application/json','Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'true'});
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return response;
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load ');
    }
}

Comment: Now you have removed the old error. Does this mean its a new error? Did you try my suggested answer.?

Comment: This one was a new error at the time. Your suggestions were right. after a while this issue was solved. I will post solution soon.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using Flutter Web and call an API, Flutter uses:
**Preflight request** (before call the API)
It is a request that checks to see if the CORS protocol is understood and a server is aware using specific methods and headers.
It is an OPTIONS request, using three HTTP request headers:

```
1.Access-Control-Request-Method,
2.Access-Control-Request-Headers,
3.and the Origin header.
```

In that case you need to check if your API is allowed for methods OPTIONS.

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://foo.bar.org
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, **OPTIONS**, DELETE

If your API not accept,  you need to configurare your response to send  OPTIONS in 
Access-Control-Allow-Methods for example:
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Request-Headers: origin, x-requested-with 
Origin: https://foo.bar.org

[More details in Mozilla Glossary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)

Answer (score 0):

The browser debugger (F12), and Wireshark between the flutter client and the server, are very valuable in figuring out this issue.

The browser debugger quickly shows it erroring on a [preflight](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-preflight/) check. There isn't anything to do here on the flutter web side. The support needs to be provided by the server.

In my case, my server is written in Go, and using Gorrila-Mux. I followed this [nice article](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/configuring-cors-for-go/) but still had an issue. I still saw in Wireshark the OPTIONS request getting denied by the server, and nothing in the server logs explaining why.

This [issue](https://github.com/gorilla/handlers/issues/133) helped me find the solution. There were a lot of incorrect answers along the way, and ultimately this is what I've learned:

1. The server must react to OPTION requests, where the client is usually sending `Access-Control-Request-Method` and `Access-Control-Request-Headers` (depends on exactly what request is being made).
2. Access control response headers from the server are required. In my case, `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` are the non-optional ones.
3. Some answers have said `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is not allowed -- it is, as the [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7480#section-5.6) explains.
4. If `Access-Control-Allowed-Methods` is sent in the response, it does NOT require OPTIONS to be listed.

Since I am using Gorilla mux, I also found the OPTIONS route does not need to be explicitly registered as a handler; the middleware will process it.

And minimally, for my apis there's just one response header that must be configured in Gorilla mux: Allowed Headers. The middleware will respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` as specified, and, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. Per comments in `cors.go`:

```
// Content-Type must be explicitly declared if accepting Content-Types other than
// application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain.
```

The response `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` automatically filters out header keys that the client didn't request.

So then my server code uses

```
import "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
```

and has

```
    cors := []handlers.CORSOption{}
    cors = append(cors, handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "POST"}))
    cors = append(cors, handlers.MaxAge(3600))
    cors = append(cors, handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Authorization"}))

    olist := []string{}
    whitelist := os.Getenv("CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS")
    if whitelist != "" {
        parts := strings.Split(whitelist, ",")
        olist = append(olist, parts...)
    }
    if len(olist) == 0 {
        olist = append(olist, "*")
    }
    cors = append(cors, handlers.AllowedOrigins(olist))
```

with

```
http.ListenAndServe(iface, handlers.CORS(cors...)(myRouter))
```

Answer (score -1):

From the comments above I assume you are using ASP .net web api. If this is the case, then  you should perhaps use the constructor for `EnableCorsAttribute` properly. As per the documentations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn314682(v=vs.118)), you have to use the first parameter in the constructor to pass allowed list of origins. In your case you can do either of the following.

#### Allow all origins

```cs
public EnableCorsAttribute(
    "*",
    "*",
    ""
)
```

#### Allow specific origins

```cs
public EnableCorsAttribute(
    "http://localhost:59789,http//localhost:another_port,http://example_domain.com",
    "*",
    ""
)
```

Also note that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is [response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin). You should not set it in your request headers. Its tells the browser or the client from which origins are allowed to access the server. Read more about CORS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).